# is it necessary to register an adapter before opening a Hive Box

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I have this approach
the `opnHiveBoxes()` opens boxes, one of theme store only element of `FavoriteApi` which I register its adapter before `theopnHiveBoxes()` call

```
  await init.HiveFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(FavoriteApiAdapter());
  await opnHiveBoxes();
```

this works fine, when I do:

```
  await init.HiveFlutter();
  await opnHiveBoxes();  
  Hive.registerAdapter(FavoriteApiAdapter());
```

works also fine, but for safety, I just wanna know if this is normal or if this may cause errors or weird behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the practical answer, is **no**, there is no problem with registering the `Hive` adapter before opening a box, what you should consider, is to not call the write and read methods such as `get()`, `put()`, `putAt()`, `getAt()`..., before you register the adapter

but it's recommended ti always register the adapter before the `runApp()` method begin to execute.